# Find probability of rejecting a true null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

> A binomial experiment tests $H_0$ : p = 0.5 against p $\neq$ 0.5 using
>   significance level 0.05. Only 5 observations are available. Show that
>   the probability to reject a true null hypothesis is 1/16.

The steps for the solution:

$H_0$ : p = 0.5

$H_a$: p $\neq$ 0.5

$N$ = 5

$\alpha$ = 0.05

Pr(Type I error) = Pr(reject $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true)

The formula implemented from [Hypothesis testing, page 12](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~arpaiva/classes/UT_ece3530/hypothesis_testing.pdf)

$\sum_{x=1}^5 b(x, n = 5, p = 0.5) = \sum_{x=1}^5  \binom{5}{n} 0.5^x0.95^{5-x} $

but it doesn't get the answer 1 / 16.

Any suggestion what's wrong ?

Comment: Is this an exact binomial test or are you using the normal approximation to the sample proportion?

Comment: @AdamO Binomial test seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For calculating the probability of a Type I Error, we start with:
$$
\begin{equation} \label{eql}
\begin{split}
\text{Pr}(\text{Type I Error}) & = \text{Pr}(\text{reject }H_0 | H_0 \text{ is true}) \\ & = \text{Pr}(\text{reject }H_0 | p=.5, n=5) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

The probability mass function $\text{Pr}(X=x)=\binom{5}{x}.5^x .5^{5-x}$ (note that your *pmf* incorrectly uses $1-p=.95$) for a binomial random variable $X$  given our $H_0$ ($p=.5,n=5$) is:
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Pr}(X=0) = \frac{1}{32} = .03125 \\
\text{Pr}(X=1) = \frac{5}{32} = .15625 \\
\text{Pr}(X=2) = \frac{5}{16} = .31250 \\
\text{Pr}(X=3) = \frac{5}{16} = .31250 \\
\text{Pr}(X=4) = \frac{5}{32} = .15625 \\
\text{Pr}(X=5) = \frac{1}{32} = .03125
\end{split}
$$

Noting above that only $\text{Pr}(X=0)$ and $\text{Pr}(X=5)$ are below our $\alpha=.05$ threshold, and therefore that $H_0$ may only be rejected if a sample results in $X=0$ or $X=5$, we can move forward as follows:

$$
\begin{equation} \label{eql1}
\begin{split}
\text{Pr}(\text{Type I Error}) & = \text{Pr}(\text{reject }H_0 | p=.5,n=5) \\ & = \text{Pr}(X=0| p=.5,n=5) + \text{Pr}(X=5| p=.5,n=5) \\ & =2\cdot.03125=.0625=\frac{1}{16}
\end{split}   
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: But this doesn't meet the goal of having the false alarm probability being    at most $0.05$; the false alarm probability is $0.0625 > 0.05$.

Comment: is missing the 0 in .5 some kind of convention here ?

Comment: also why are 6 observations made(0-5) ?

Comment: 1) Not really - some people do it, some don't.  It's a matter of preference, and I find it to be more easily readable.

2) A total of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 successes can possibly be observed, because there are 5 observations in the experiment.  An example would be being able to flip anywhere from 0 to 5 heads when flipping n=5 times.

Comment: In other words, there are 6 possible outcomes of the experiment when you make 5 observations.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the significance level is doing in this *hypothesis* test or what its meaning might be, but stripped of all the malarkey and statistical verbiage, on 5 tosses of a fair coin, the probability of tossing 5 heads *or* 5 tails is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{32}+ \frac{1}{32}= \frac{1}{16}$. Any reasonable test of the hypothesis $H_0$ that $p=0.5$ versus the hypothesis $H_1$ that $p\neq 0.5$ must reject this event (all heads or all tails) giving a false alarm probability of $\frac{1}{16}=0.0625$ on the reasonable assumption that the *only* observation that causes rejection of $H_0$ is the all heads or all tails event.  If you insist that the false alarm probability should not *exceed* 0.05, then you either need to use an asymmetric test such as rejecting $H_0$ when you observe 5 heads but not rejecting $H_0$ when you observe 5 tails, or, more simply, never reject $H_0$ thereby achieving a false alarm probability of $0$ which, when I last checked, is smaller than the maximum allowable false alarm probability of $0.05$.

Comment: No more clarifications are given on the task, just to prove it's 1/16